# How do I initialize a struct in C based on the member's name

Tags: c, data-structures, syntax, struct

In C I often see structs init'ed like this:

```
struct size aSize;
aSize.x = 100;
aSize.y = 42;
```

But in other languages you can create struct "like" data structures in one line like:

```
aSize = {
    x : 100,
    y : 42
};
```

Is a similar syntax supported in C?

*I understand that Javascript's "struct" like data structure is really a hash without defined params, i'm just trying to show the syntax*

Comment: I think a more appropriate title would be "How do I initialize a struct in C based on the member's name" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C99 allows the following for "*order agnostic*" initilization:

```
struct aSize {
    int x;
    int y;
} aSize = { .y = 4, .x = 5 };
```

See [**this link**](http://www.ideone.com/oIqSv) for a working example